# Android Use different manifest depending on SDK Platform Version

Tags: android, android-manifest

Is it possible for manifest properties to change based on Android SDK versions?

eg: have `android:largeHeap` be `true` when SDK version < 24 and `false` when SDK >= 24?

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.androidapp">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"

        android:largeHeap="true" 

        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try This

***res/values/bool.xml***

```
<resources>
    <bool name="largeheap">true</bool>
</resources>
```

***res/values-v24/bool.xml***

```
<resources>
    <bool name="largeheap">false</bool>
</resources>
```

***Android Manifest file:***

```
<application
        android:largeHeap="@bool/largeheap"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher">
                ....
</application>
```

Make `true` in `res/values/bool.xml` and `false` in `res/values-v24/bool.xml`. Android API Level 24, so `-v24` will be used for 24 and higher versions.

Answer (score 1):

**The answer is no. But you can merge (override SDK specific libraries) them like**

```
  <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="com.example.app"
          xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
  <uses-sdk tools:overrideLibrary="com.example.lib1, com.example.lib2"/>
    ...
```

source: [Developer.Android](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/manifest-merge)

Comment: This work for lib which has minSdkVersion > your minSdkVersion